# Need help. Trying to figure out how to make a task bar for OS through Github in typescript

Tags: typescript, date, github, operating-system, taskbar

Enhance the host display with a graphic task bar that displays...

• the   current date    and time

• status    messages    as  specified   by  the user    with    a   new shell   command:
status 
example:status I love Operating Systems

I have a date object already created:
``

```
    public shellDate(args: string[]) {
         let shelldate = new Date ();
         _StdOut.putText(shelldate.toString());   
            
    }
```

I am confused on how I code and implement the task bar object

Comment: What is "a task bar object"? Please describe your goal in detail, and describe the problem you are having in detail. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then [edit] your question with more information.